# How to Programmatically Scroll Drawer in Material UI React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Can someone please help? 
This is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/5xoj9zw56l

I followed this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/6jr75xj8y3

Comment: Please add essential parts here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawer creates an elements, it will have structure like this

```
parent div > nested div > your data
```

And while getting the ref into drawer you do not get that div reference which you need to scroll.

What you need to do is you can add ref to your data `div` and go through `ref.parent` this way you will have parent div ref and there you can scroll the element.

To scroll you must have ref of div where you applied the overflow.

Here is the changes you need to do

Instead of container you will get aprent element

```
handleScrollTo = () => {

    console.log(this.container.parentElement.scrollTop);
    this.container.parentElement.scrollTop = 200;
  };
```

instead of using ref on drawer using the data on scroll

```
<Drawer open={this.state.left} onClose={this.toggleDrawer( "left", false)} onScroll={e=> console.log("scroll " + e.target.scrollTop)} >
  <div ref={el=> (this.container = el)} tabIndex={1} role="button" onKeyDown={this.toggleDrawer("left", false)} > {sideList} </div>
</Drawer>
```

[Here is demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/5wy7r2jk7x)

Comment: Your technique works great! Thanks so much. How do I make it auto scroll when the Drawer is open? This code doesn't work: 
`<Drawer  onOpen={() => {
          this.handleScrollTo();
        }}>`